# Statusbar style on state restoration

Tags: objective-c, state-restoration

Is there any way to reset statusbar style during the app launch to the one that was used when the app state was preserved (saved)?

Comment: @SG1 I guess it's impossible. I simply hide status bar during app start, there is a flag for that in project settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to store a `UIStatusBarStyle` which is a `typedef` for int. When you are about to quit the application, store the current status bar style in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults setInteger:<my status bar style> forKey:@"style"];
// can use things like UIStatusBarStyleLightContent for <my status bar style>
```

Then when you want to retrieve this you can do the following.

```
UIStatusBarStyle style = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"style"];
```

Comment: The OS did not return control to UIApplicationDelegate yet, so I cannot run code. The status bar style used for splash screen apparently used from Info.plist, but I would like to restore the same style as it was on screen when application state was saved. Sometimes i get default style from plist, sometimes the same used on state preservation. I can't find the reason why it's different from time to time.

Comment: I haven't actually tested this, but with iOS 8's new splash screen view controller system, you should be able to use this solution to return the -preferredStatusBarStyle for the view controller at runtime.